# Why is the PendingIntent firing?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, alarmmanager, java-time

I'm trying to send notifications on specific days. My method "setNextNotification" schedules the next notification using AlarmManager.

Java Time API is used to check the current day. If it is equal to Tuesday, a day is added to the ZonedDateTime and an alarm is set to that day. This is at least what I'm trying to accomplish.

It's Tuesday today and a notification is fired anyway.

What am I missing?

```
private static void setNextNotification(Context context) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm"));
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = zdt.getDayOfWeek();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        if(dayOfWeek.getValue() == 2){
            zdt.plusDays(1);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), alarmIntent);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZonedDateTime` is an immutable representation of a date-time with a time-zone. So, even though you called `plusDays(1)`, the original time in `ZoneDateTime` object remains unchanged.

The `plusDays()` returns a new `ZonedDateTime` object with the modified value. Which in your code you're not assigning anywhere. So you need to replace

`zdt.plusDays(1);` with `zdt = zdt.plusDays(1);`

in order for it to work as you intended.

Modified code:

```
private static void setNextNotification(Context context) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm"));
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = zdt.getDayOfWeek();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        if(dayOfWeek.getValue() == 2){
            zdt = zdt.plusDays(1);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), alarmIntent);
        }

}
```

Comment: I clearly see now why I should have paid more attention to "immutable". It's like a String! Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @OlaBandola Good to hear it worked! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However there is no obligation to do this.